# Ansible etcd lookup plugin issue

Tags: ansible, etcd

I've etcd running on the Ansible control machine (local). I can get and put the values as shown below but Ansible wouldn't get values, any thoughts?

[image]

I can also get the value using curl

[image]

I got this simple playbook

```
#!/usr/bin/env ansible-playbook
---
- name: simple ansible playbook ping
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:    
  - name: look up value in etcd
    debug: msg="{{ lookup('etcd', 'weather') }}"
```

And running this playbook wouldn't fetch values from etcd

```
TASK: [look up value in etcd]     *************************************************
ok: [app1.test.com] => {
    "msg": ""
}
ok: [app2.test.com] => {
    "msg": ""
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently (31.05.2016) Ansible etcd lookup plugin support only calls to v1 API and not compatible with newer etcd instances that publish v2 API endpoint.
Here is the [issue](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/13946).

You can use my quickly patched [etcd2.py](https://gist.github.com/berlic/98fcd4d80c6db78e946e9f9f31d65510) lookup plugin.
Place it into `lookup_plugins` subdirectory near you playbook (or into Ansible global lookup_plugins path).

Use `lookup('etcd2', 'weather')` in your playbook.

Comment: Thanks. Precisely the solution.